# How to get specific values from firebase realtime database.Similar to a where clause in sql

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Am kind of new to android and firebase but I need to get some values from my firebase realtime database similar to a select stmt in sql(select address,name from All_machines where terminal_id = "terminal_id").
When i did the code below i was getting a null pointer exeception. But I guess am yet to understand the concept.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("All Machines");
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (childDataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
                    try {
                        if (childDataSnapshot.child("terminal_id").getValue().toString().equals(newTerminal_id)){
                            String Terminal_address= ""+ childDataSnapshot.child("address").getValue();
                            String Terminal_name = ""+ childDataSnapshot.child("terminal_name").getValue();
                            terminal_name.setText(Terminal_name);
                            terminal_address.setText(Terminal_address);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Entry matching barcode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        //Log.v(TAG,""+ childDataSnapshot.child("terminal_name").getValue());   //gives the value for given keyname
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It's null.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //Log.v(TAG,""+ childDataSnapshot.getKey()); //displays the key for the node
                //get the terminal id for each child then check if it matches the scanned barcode

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**Database Structure:**

```
{
  "All Machines": {
    "-M-JnXkserObKnDj3iZO": {
      "address": "OANDO IDIROKO",
      "atmClass": "6627",
      "bankName": "SPL",
      "brand": "NCR",
      "id": "-M-JnXkserObKnDj3iZO",
      "ip": "1033944",
      "latitude": "10333",
      "longitude": "10333",
      "serial_no": "13528891",
      "terminal_Id": "10332368",
      "terminal_name": "ATM9"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add ur database to the question

Comment: Can you add your database strucutre?

Comment: "When i did the code below i was getting a null pointer exeception" If you get an exception, find the exact error message and complete stack trace in your logcat output and add them to your question. In addition, as others have asked, we'll need to see the JSON at `All Machines` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `orderByChild` and `equalTo` methods to filter data in server side like below:

```
// Get DatabaseReference for All Machines
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("All Machines");

// Use orderByChild to order data by terminal_Id and use equalTo for filter by newTerminal_id
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("terminal_Id").equalTo(newTerminal_id);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String Terminal_address= childSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class);
            String Terminal_name = childSnapshot.child("terminal_name").getValue(String.class);

            terminal_name.setText(Terminal_name);
            terminal_address.setText(Terminal_address);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**Output:** If `terminal_Id` equals **10332368**, then

```
Terminal_address = "OANDO IDIROKO";
Terminal_name = "ATM9";
```

Comment: @Moresky, have you checked that? According your database you have to use `terminal_Id` instead of `terminal_id`.

Comment: thanks for that observation. Working fine now after changing to terminal_Id.